# How to open file properties dialog in kde plasma (Kubuntu Linux) from terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde, kubuntu

In kubuntu desktop you can open file properties dialog by right click on the file on desktop and select Properties or select file and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> to open file properties dialog.
in files app of kde plasma this properties dialog difference from this dialog that open from desktop right click.
I would to open properties dialog from terminal with a command and passing file path to it for open dialog like desktop right clicking.
I hope you know a way

Like this images :
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use kioclient to open the file properties dialog:

```
kioclient openProperties "/path/to/file"
```

Comment: If a citation is of worth, it is https://invent.kde.org/plasma/kde-cli-tools/-/blob/a28aa65941fcea5afed13459168ab18599ac5dd0/kioclient/kioclient.cpp#L56.